# 'userMultidexKeepFile' does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:multiDexListRelease' (type 'D8MainDexListTask').

File 'C:\Users\PIANO\AndroidStudioProjects\Sigma\app\multidex-config.txt' specified for property 'userMultidexKeepFile' does not exist.

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue (including searching online)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missing file `'C:\Users\PIANO\AndroidStudioProjects\Sigma\app\multidex-config.txt`

if not the case , You should check out [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#multidexkeepfile-property) text